# How to get name of scenario in cucumber java?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I would like to get name of scenario to have meaningful logs and to generate custom report at run-time in java. Scenario class have only has getStatus() and getSourceTagNames() methods. I don't find a way to get scenario name.

Can someone help me to get this resolved ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From version 1.6, in addition to, `getStatus()` and `getSourceTagNames()`, there is another method, `getName()` that returns the scenario's description.
For example, for a scenario as follows:

```
Scenario: verify number of topics shown in the UI
```

`scenario.getName()` returns `"verify number of topics shown in the UI"`

I initialize scenario in @Before as follows:

```
@Before
public void before(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually forgot to mention the version of cucumber which I'm using. I was trying with version 1.5. Tried with 1.6 and it worked.

Comment: Does Cucumber have something like step.getName() ? To get the name of the current Step being executed.

Comment: when using Scenario Oulines, Name will not be unique.

Comment: Can this work for features as well, or only scenarios?

Comment: You forgot to mention that \@Before Hooks go in the Step Definition file, not the Runner that specifies the \@RunWith(Cucumber.class) and 
\@CucumberOptions annotations.

Answer (score 1):

```
String scenarioName = scenario.getName();
String[] arrayScenarioName = scenarioName.split("--");
String scenarioName1 = arrayScenarioName[0]; 
String scenarioName2 = arrayScenarioName[1]; 
System.out.println("Scenario Name 1 for this test is -> " + scenarioName1);
System.out.println("Scenario Name 2 for this test is -> " + scenarioName2);

String scenarioId = scenario.getId();
//Takes the Scenario ID and removes the ; and splits it into 2 strings
String scenarioId4 = scenarioId;
String[] parts = scenarioId4.split(";");
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1]; 
String part11 = part1.replace('-', ' ');
String part22 = part2.replace('-', ' ');
System.out.println("Scenario ID for this test is -> part11 " + part11);
System.out.println("Scenario ID for this test is -> part22 " + part22);
```

Once you have the @Before set up them try this to retrieve your Cucumber Feature and Scenario items.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the step definition, you can use `CucumberHelper.scenario.getName()`.

Based on this API you can use `getID`, `getSourceTagNames`, `getStatus` and `getClass` methods.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea.
However, where is CucumberHelper defined?

Comment: You can create a helper class and import `cucumber.api.Scenario;` and declare the Scenario as static inside the class to have it available. `public static Scenario scenario;`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the entire code for the problem asked, to save your time:

```
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
Scenario scenario;

   @Before
    public void before(Scenario scenario) {
        this.scenario = scenario;
    }

    @Given("I test scenario name")
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(scenario.getName());
    }
```

Comment: this will not work with parallel tests...