# Can I get the scenario description for use within the test

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, serenity-bdd

In my feature files I have scenario and scenario outlines in gherkin. I would like to get those descriptions within the tests that they define. For example

```
Scenario: Create a customer
```

or

```
Scenario Outline: Create a customer that has <item> items (item fed by a table)
```

I want to use the description above in the test it defines for ease of knowing what test put what user into the database. Is there a way to get this description from within the test?

A

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23602953/how-to-get-name-of-scenario-in-cucumber-java

Comment: it does indeed. exactly what I needed. thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hooks (see https://www.baeldung.com/java-cucumber-hooks)

```java
@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) { 
    System.out.println("Before scenario " + scenario.getName());
}
```

If you want to share this between steps, and you are using cucumber-spring, you may want to use the `cucumber-glue` scope.

```java
public class MyContext {
   private Scenario scenario;

   public void setScenario(Scenario scenario) {
      this.scenario = scenario;
   }

   public Scenario getScenario() {
      if (this.scenario == null) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Scenario has not been set");
      }
      return this.scenario;
   }
}

@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {
   @Bean @Scope("cucumber-glue")
   public MyContext myContext() {
      return new MyContext();
   }
}

public class MySteps1 {
   @Autowired
   private MyContext myContext;

   @Before
   public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) { 
      myContext.setScenario(scenario);
   }

   @When(...) 
   public void whenX() { ... }
}

public class MySteps2 {
   @Autowired
   private MyContext myContext;

   @When("something happens")
   public void whenSomethingHappens() { 
      System.out.println("About to do something for " + scenario.getName());
   }
}
```